# Qt 4.6 + MinGW: suppress warnings for generated code

Tags: c++, qt, warnings, mingw, pragma

We are using Axis2 (WSDL2C) to generate `*.c/*.h` files from WSDLs in order to be able to call webservices with Qt 4.6. But the generated code creates a massive amount of warnings (3 services -> >1k warnings), mostly about uninitialized or unused variables. How can we suppress these warnings properly?

I know I can wrap headers in `#pragma` to suppress warnings from 3rd party libs, but how to deal with generated code where the warnings come from the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this line to your Qt .pro or .pri file:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -Wno-unused
```

It turns off unused warning.

Comment: Well, that means I would have to move all the generated code into a different project or I would lose all "unused" warnings which are caused by my code?

Comment: @atamanroman. Yes, you will have to move them into a sub-project or sort if you want to keep the warning in your own code.

Comment: @atamanroman Yes, it looks like you have very good reason to move this code to separate project :)

Answer (score 1):

The code generator is Apache, i.e. Open Source. Have you had a peek at the source? Perhaps you can patch that?

Comment: Thats true and its a long term goal for me personally, but I guess thats going to be a spare time project.